# '<module:ActiveRecord>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Mount (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, carrierwave

i have this error when try to run `rspec` i'm using:

`rails 4.2.4
ruby 2.2.2
carrierwave 0.10.0`

what can i do?!

```
/home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:9:in `<module:ActiveRecord>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Mount (NameError)
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:7:in `<module:CarrierWave>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /home/code/bedo/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/code/bedo/spec/rails_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/code/bedo/spec/controllers/assignments_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/adham/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have solved this problem by requiring `carrierwave orm` after requiring the `application` file at `config/environment.rb` file.

`require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'`